# Caroufredsel infinite linear easing is adding margin after the last image that fits on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, caroufredsel

I'm using the CarouFredsel jQuery plugin at http://chiaroscurodev.telegraphbranding.com/ and as you can see, it is calculating the number of WHOLE images that will fit on the screen given the width of the browser. It then adds margin after that last image before scrolling the next images.

My code:

```
$("#carousel").carouFredSel({
            width       : "100%",
            auto: { 
                duration        : 40000,
                easing          : "linear",
                timeoutDuration : 0,
                pauseOnHover    : "immediate"
            }

        });
```

I would like the carousel to infinitely scroll 100% of the browser without adding any margin after each image, just a constant stream of images.

Also, does anyone know how I could implement a feature where when you click an image it slides the carousel so that image is centered in the browser?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: how did you solve this problem? was it by switching carousel libraries?